# Delete object returned by a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

Let's suppose I have an object like this

```
var $obj = {
    0 : {
        'id' : 3,
        'label' : 'Item One'
    },
    1 : {
        'id' : 7,
        'label' : 'Item Two'
    }
}
```

And a function like this:

```
function findById(obj, id){
    var result = false;
    $.each(obj, function(index, element){
        if(element.id === id)
        {
            result = element;
            return false;//stops $.each iteration
        }
    })
    return result;
}
```

Now, let's suppose I want to delete the item with id "7" programmatically, like triggered by a click, anyway I fire my function like this:

```
delete findById($obj, 7);
```

After this "delete" the property with key 1 and id=7 is still there.
I know I'm missing something but I cannot get out of this xD.
How should I get the property removed from the original object? I'm sure is something about scope or anyway very basic in javascript which I still cannot understad. But I go on encountering such problems and cannot find a complete answer to this question.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me with this ;)

Comment: You are deleting result, returned by function call, but object's field.

Answer (score 0):

When you iterate an object with `$.each`  what you are referring to as `index` is actually the object key.

Since your `findById()` doesn't return that key you might want a separate method for deleting

```js
var $obj = {
    0 : {
        'id' : 3,
        'label' : 'Item One'
    },
    1 : {
        'id' : 7,
        'label' : 'Item Two'
    }
}

function deleteById(obj, id){    
    $.each(obj, function(key, element){
        if(element.id === id) {
           delete obj[key]
           return false;//stops $.each iteration
        }
    });   
}

deleteById($obj, 7)

console.log($obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: this would be an option for my current setup. Is there anything simpler?
I wonder why I can edit the returned object's properties (like edit the label), but cannot delete it on the fly

Comment: Because you are returning the child object but have no reference to it's parent. Might also be simpler to use an array of objects instead of a single object. Using array methods makes it easy to `find()` or get index of an object within an array

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, you want to delete the property that matches the selected item from the original object, right?

```js
function findById(obj, id){
    var result = false;
    $.each(obj, function(index, element){
    
        // here the index is the name of the property on the original item. So "A", "B" etc.
        console.dir(index);
        if(element.id === id)
        {
            // you will need to know the name of the property you want to delete, not its value.
            result = index;
            return false;//stops $.each iteration
        }
    })
    return result;
}

var $obj = {
    "A" : {
        'id' : 3,
        'label' : 'Item One'
    },
    "B" : {
        'id' : 7,
        'label' : 'Item Two'
    }
}

// first you get the property name.
var propertyName = findById($obj, 7);
console.dir("Property to delete is: "+ propertyName);

console.dir("Original object before property deletion:");
console.dir($obj);
delete $obj[propertyName];
console.dir("Original object after property deletion:");
console.dir($obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Some explanations:
`delete` performs the deletion of a property from a JavaScript object ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete)).
Your original object has two properties, "A" and "B". You want to remove item "B" from the object - in JavaScript that means removing the property from the object.
Therefore, what you need to do is passing to the delete method the reference to the property to remove: that's why I have altered the `findById` function to return the "index" (aka the name) of the element instead of its actual value.
The final instruction, `delete $obj[propertyName];` makes use of the fact that proprieties names in JavaScript can also be used as an indexer of the object. Therefore, in this specific case, the line can be seen as equivalent to `delete $obj.B`.

Comment: The real object is more complex than what I showed in my example, I have 3 nested levels with unique id but not unique index. So unfortunately this one is not an option for my current setup... :\

Comment: something like this

var $obj = {
    0 : {
        'id' : 3,
        'label' : 'Item One',
        'children': {
            0 : {
                'id' : 5,
                'label' : 'Item Two',
                'children': {
                    0 : {
                        'id' : 13,
                        'label' : 'Item Three'
                    }
                }
            },
            1 : {
                'id' : 9,
                'label' : 'Item Four'
            }
        }
    },
    1 : {
        'id' : 7,
        'label' : 'Item Five'
    }
}

Comment: @MichelePazzi will try to rework that to match your requirements but right now I can guarantee nothing. Please give me some time.

Comment: thank you in any case, now I'm deleting by using another function. But any simpler approach is welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion the simplest "`one liner`" solutions is to return the index. it will give you some benefits

1. you will not need to create new function
2. your old function will not loss it's functionality

then you can delete the object by the returned index.

please checkout my `snippet` and please comment if there anything i can help to improve my answer.

have a nice day..

```js
var $obj = {
    0 : {
        'id' : 3,
        'label' : 'Item One'
    },
    1 : {
        'id' : 7,
        'label' : 'Item Two'
    }
}

function findById(obj, id){
    var result = false;
    $.each(obj, function(index, element){
        if(element.id === id)
        {
            result = element;
            
            //return the index
            result.index = index;
            
            return false;//stops $.each iteration
        }
    })
    return result;
}

//delete object by index
delete $obj[findById($obj, 7).index]


console.log($obj)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The real object is more complex than what I showed in my example, I have 3 nested levels with unique id but not unique index. So unfortunately this one is not an option for my current setup... :\

Comment: can you please give me the example of your more complex object..? i've done similar solutions in my project where i need to delete specific deep nested object. but just in case, please share complex obj example, so i can improve my answer..

Comment: var $obj = {
    0 : {
        'id' : 3,
        'label' : 'Item One',
        'children': {
            0 : {
                'id' : 5,
                'label' : 'Item Two',
                'children': {
                    0 : {
                        'id' : 13,
                        'label' : 'Item Three'
                    }
                }
            },
            1 : {
                'id' : 9,
                'label' : 'Item Four'
            }
        }
    },
    1 : {
        'id' : 7,
        'label' : 'Item Five'
    }
}

Comment: And I'm planning to use the index / numeric key for sorting purposes, by the way my actual findById function is recursive to find the id in children too

Answer (score 0):

if you had an array of objects instead of a collection you could use `filter` function

```
var $obj = [
   {
      'id' : 3,
      'label' : 'Item One'
   },
   {
      'id' : 7,
      'label' : 'Item Two'
    }
];

function deleteElementByID($obj, id){
  return $obj.filter(function(item){
    return item.id != id;
  });
}
```

if you can't or don't want to convert it to an Array, then you can use jQuery's map function:

```
function deleteElementByID(id){
  $obj = $.map($obj,function(item,index){
    if(item.id != id) return item;
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm deleting by using another function now, that works for now ;)

Comment: Fair enough, did you try the solutions above? Did they work?